# Angular md-tabs, not scrolling up to the end of the web page

Tags: html, css, angularjs

[image: normal view]
[image: if I resize and scroll down, still looks normal]
[image: when I click at one of the <code>li</code> there's a template for the data that will be appended on the list]

1st image - normal view 
2nd image - if I resize and scroll down, still looks normal 
3rd image - when I click at one of the `li` there's a template for the data that will be appended on the list

The problem is that on the 3rd image, there are still other data to show but those are not shown. I can't scroll further down to show the remaining data.

I also noticed that the scrollbar is chopped off at the end, its not curved/rounded.

BTW, the content of the tab is an iframe. `external-app-template.pug` is appended to the `div` inside the `md-tab-body`

Main technologies used:

```
angular - 1.5.7
pug - 2.0.0-alpha6
gulp - 3.9.1
gulp-pug - 3.0.3
gulp-less - 3.1.0
babel-core - 6.10.4
```

HTML(Pug) - index.pug:

```
body
  div(layout="column" layout-fill ng-include="'layout/layout.template.html'" ng-controller="LayoutController as vm")
    div.scrollable(ng-if="vm.user" layout="column" flex)
      md-tabs(md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="vm.selectedTab")
        md-tab(ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs" ng-disabled="tab.disabled")
          md-tab-label {{tab.label}} {{tab.extraLabel}}
          md-tab-body
            div(ng-include="tab.template" dynamic-controller="tab.controller" prospect="vm.prospect")
```

HTML(Pug) - external-app-template.pug:

```
div(layout="column" flex)
  iframe(ng-show="is_ready" src="{{iframe_url}}" flex)
```

CSS(Less) - main.less:

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
md-tabs,
md-tabs-content-wrapper,
md-tab-content,
md-tab-content div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML(Pug) - external-app.pug

```
body(ng-controller="ctrl" style="height: {{frame_height}}px;")
  md-content#main-container
```

CSS(Less) - external-app.less

```
#main-container {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

JS(Babel) - external-app.js

```
window.addEventListener("resize", (ev) => {
  $scope.frame_height = document.body.clientHeight - 20;
});
```